# Why wasn't SpaceX heavy rocket tested thoroughly on ground before being sent to space?

Tags: spacex, rockets, propulsion

I do not know how much testing SpaceX did before launching their heavy rocket but it to blow up 3 mins later and call is a success seems a bit misleading. I understand they gathered data but to what end? They lost 3 billion craft. Lets say they do another test and it blows up 6 mins later for whatever reason. Another 3 billion gone. They do another test and goes for an hour and blows up during reentry. Then what? Is it still a success?

Why wasn't SpaceX heavy rocket tested thoroughly on ground before being sent to space? Assuming they took shortcuts and said screw it lets fire it up and see what happens, at what point will they say we are running out of money and cannot make anymore? Then what happens?

As an engineer and a software developer I test & retest and continue every possible testing scenarios before releasing code to production. I understand rockets and software developed arent the same but I feel public is being misled by "success" of this flight. Am I incorrect to assume that?

Comment: This Starship was always going to be lost, even if it worked perfectly.  No landing attempt was planned for either the booster or Starship.

Comment: $3 billion? where did you get **that** number from? This isn't the SLS; I guarantee that number is at least an order of magnitude too high, if not two.

Comment: @fyrepenguin I read it on news and did a google search on "how much did spacex starship cost"

Comment: The question in your title is good, but the opinions you are expressing in your question are leading to downvotes (not by me). Consider rewording it to leave out the editorial comments and just ask why SpaceX didn't do a more thorough ground testing regime.

Comment: @SamB, 3 billion might be plausible for the total project cost since the first design studies in 2016.  It's certainly not the cost of building a rocket.

Comment: Ironically, it's the ground that turned out to need more thorough testing.

Comment: @SamB a good comparison for you is that 1 SLS total cost is in the range of 2 billion per rocket, with a total development cost in the 20+ billion range. Starship's *total development cost* thus far is closer to the 3 billion you mention, but the **per rocket cost** is certainly far, far lower. As has been mentioned, they have multiple other rockets near completion and have scrapped others, so it's not like any given rocket is *that* expensive.

Comment: Considering that the *entire NASA Artemis Human Landing System program* costs less than \$3 billion, and includes, among other things, a completely new launch pad at Kennedy Space Center, the development of 3 new Starship variants, the building of between 3 and 20 new Starships and Super Heavy boosters, the development of a space suit, the development of in-orbit refilling, a demonstration flight for in-orbit refilling, crew-rating the Starship system, and two landings on the Moon, including one takeoff, it seems pretty obvious that the \$3 billion figure *cannot possibly* be real.

Answer (score 15):

It *was* tested heavily on the ground.  Pressurization tests, fueling tests, spin-prime tests, static fires of all 33 engines individually and as a group.

Thing is, there are things it's impossible to test beforehand.

There are no hypersonic wind tunnels large enough to accommodate a 120-meter-tall rocket, and such a wind tunnel would involve energy levels commonly associated with small nuclear weapons.  This makes it impossible to test things like the turbulence around the aft skirt and engines ahead of time.

There are no vacuum chambers large enough to accommodate such a rocket, or even the engine section alone.  That makes it impossible to test how the exhaust expansion from 33 nozzles interacts at high altitudes, among other things.

There are no reduced-gravity facilities large enough to accommodate the rocket.  This means you can't test things like the separation mechanism or the second-stage ullage system in flight conditions.

In software-engineering terms, this wasn't a production release, this was an integration test.  SpaceX is doing something that hasn't been seen in aerospace since the 1950s: hardware-rich testing, where you rapidly iterate by building rockets, launching them, and seeing what breaks.  It's a much faster way of designing things than the "analyze it to death" method everyone's used to, but it also produces more explosions.

This was booster 7 and Starship 24.  Boosters 9 and 10 and Starships 25 and 26 are currently waiting for the launch pad to be repaired so they can be tested in turn.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I read somewhere that SpaceX motto is to Fail Fast and fix problems on next launch. But that approach has risks, financial risks. On the other hand NASA approach is to analyze every possible failure and mitigate risks which takes very long time. Perhaps you can add a few paragraphs about SpaceX approach risks

Comment: @SamB, I'm not sure it *has* financial risks.  Starship/Super Heavy is intended to be a cheap, mass-produced rocket -- something more akin to a Boeing 737 than the Space Shuttle.  Everything we've seen so far is basically byproducts of figuring out how to make a rocket factory.

Comment: The one major test that SpaceX could theoretically have done but didn't was a full duration firing of the first stage on the ground.  NASA did that with the Shuttle and SLS liquid propulsion systems prior to flight. Problem is, that requires a massive and massively expensive test stand. If your goal is to make inexpensive rockets, it's a lot cheaper just to launch them and let them fail...*to a point*.

Comment: Note that Booster 8, a near identical build to Booster 7, was scrapped. For B7/S24, it was either be expended in a test flight or be scrapped as well. These were old builds, with hydraulic TVC and other things that have been changed in newer prototypes. Their only value was as test articles, and they'd gotten just about everything useful they could out of B7/S24 without flying them.

Comment: @SamB: The most expensive part of the Starship program is the development of the *factory*. You should really not look at the Starship program as a program to develop a cheap, fully and rapidly re-usable superheavy lift launch system but rather as a program to develop **a factory to mass-produce** a cheap, fully and rapidly re-usable superheavy lift launch system. In other words, SpaceX wants to become the Tesla of the launch industry: lots of companies build electric cars. But Tesla builds them *faster* than everybody else. If you look at it this way, then the vehicles come almost for free.

Comment: Case in point: SpaceX to date has built over 20 Starships (another 2 are almost finished) and several Super Heavy boosters (another one is almost finished). They are building them much faster than they can launch them: at this point, they have blown up 9, successfully launched and recovered 4, scrapped around 10 and they still have 3 ships and 1 booster sitting around ready to start their launch campaign. 7 and S24 were already obsolete: they use hydraulic thrust vector control, whereas SpaceX has switched to electric. B7's engine skirts were cobbled together, B9 has much improved ones, etc.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I wonder if you can expand that (full duration firing) into a short additional answer? It seems to explain a lot. I haven't been following closely but it looks like a vertical test wouldn't have even been possible considering the launch pad damage sustained from launch...

Comment: @uhoh not smart enough on the subject to write an answer. The "massive and massively expensive test stand" I mentioned is what would have been needed to prevent damage to the launch pad during a test firing.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, there's also the need to provide 17 million pounds of tiedowns to keep the engines from trying to put the test stand into orbit.